# iTunes iPhone Sync Issue

Tags: windows-xp, iphone, itunes

My phone isn't syncing correctly. I plug the phone into iTunes and the phone is verified. It then says "syncing iPhone" (the stage before copying music, podcasts, app, etc) forever, and seems to make no progress. I iTunes just unplugs the phone and it never finishes the sync. Can any one help? My iPhone is a 3G and the OS of the PC is running Windows XP.

My friend is also having this issue with there iPhone 3GS

Comment: A few questions: What version of iTunes are you running? Is your iPhone jailbroken? What version of the iPhone OS are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting a few days it just started to sync ok, I did not do or change anything to have syncing work.

Answer (score 0):

An outdated driver can be the cause for the issue. You can update Apple Mobile Device Driver to fix it.

1. Press Windows+ R to open Run window, type “devmgmt.msc” and hit Enter to open **Device Manager**.
2. Expand Universal Serial Bus controllers > Right-click **Apple Mobile Device USB Driver**.
3. Select **Update Driver Software** and Search automatically for updated driver software.